# Call Stack of a Selected frame

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am debugging a segmentation fault from the core file and trying to get as much info as possible. Below is a snippet of my `bt` command.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000007d4cf1 in alloc_real (vv=0x7f259e9bed20, drop_ssr=false) task_remove.c:2350
#1  0x00000000007d54f8 in ssr_unalloc (vv=0x7f259e9bed20, skip_tree=1 '\001', remove_from_sysmgr=0 '\000') at task_remove.c:2541
#2  0x00000000007e5afb in remove_done (vv=0x7f259e9bed20, status=TE_PASS, multiple_ssr=2) at task_remove.c:7058
#3  0x00000000007ee0f4 in remove_callback (task=0x7f259e9e27d0) at task_remove.c:8790
#4  0x00000000006fe4d5 in proc (arg=0x7f259e9e27d0) at smtproc.c:140
#5  0x00007f25a2cab637 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f25a55ed998 in ?? ()
```

From `bt` I can know that the program failed in `task_remove.c:2350` while executing line no 2350 of the `alloc_real` function.
The code for `'alloc_real'` has several other function calls which has passed and hence removed from the stack.

My question is, 
Is there any way/mechanism to get the `bt` of `frame 0`, or in other words all the functions called by '`alloc_real`' using gdb.

Comment: A core dump is just a snapshot of the moment of the crash. Information about what happened before it is not directly available, but might be indirectly derived from the memory contents. Eg. start by checking the variable values to see if it gives you a clue as to what happened.

Comment: _in other words all the functions called by 'alloc_real' using gdb ?_ I think `Cscope` can help you to know the function called by `alloc_real()`. Since you know the crash happened in particular function, run the `cscope` & use `printf` to debug.

Comment: Specifically: you know that `alloc_real` was called from `ssr_unalloc`, and you know which parameters it was called with. That should give you enough information to re-create the execution flow.

Comment: You can use the `list` command to show the source code context in the current frame (0) (and you can use `frame FRAME_NUMBER` to change frames).

Comment: This sounds like a job for reverse debugging. See if your gdb  supports the `record` command. Gdb doesn't record by default, so you'll need to start the process over again and hope it'll get the same error. After hitting the seg fault, you'd do `rbreak .*` to set a breakpoint in every function, then `reverse-continue`, possibly multiple times as you see each function that's called.